# Trouble with horizontial merge of csv files under Cygwin

Tags: text-processing, cygwin, newlines, paste

I have two csv files:

```
test1.csv
1
2
3
4

test2.csv
6
7
8
9
```

I want to horizontally merge these two files.  To do this I use `paste -d , test1.csv test2.csv > paste.csv`  If I open this file in notepad it looks correct i.e.

```
paste.csv
1,6
2,7
3,8
4,9
```

However if I load paste.csv in Excel it looks like

[image]

What I'm I missing?  Thanks in advance!

PS This might not matter, but I'm on windows and using Cygwin.

UPDATE: When I opened paste.csv in notepad I notice something bizarre.
There appears to be an invisible character between the number and comma.  For example, if I put my cursor between 1 and , and the hit backspace, nothing happens.  When I hit backspace again, the 1 is deleted as expected.  If I delete all these invisible characters, and then load paste.csv in excel, it is correct!

Comment: My rule of thumb when working with Windows along with a Unix-like terminal is : when in doubt, check line endings! The `CR`, `LF` and `CRLF` issues are by far the most annoying all the while staying ever so prevalent...

Comment: Based on your edit, I'd go with encoding issues. what if you do a `paste -d , test1.csv test2.csv | hexdump`, what do you get?

Comment: The problem might be directly in your command as well. What if you `echo paste -d , test1.csv test2.csv | hexdump` ?

Comment: When I try `paste -d , test1.csv test2.csv | hexdump` I get back: 0000000 0d31 362c 0a0d 0d32 372c 0a0d 0d33 382c
0000010 0a0d 0d34 392c 0a0d 2c35 3031 000a     
000001d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unix represents [newlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) with the character LF (line feed = `\n` = `^J` = 10 decimal = 012 octal = 0x0a hexadecimal). Windows represents newlines with the two-character sequence CR, LF (CR = carriage return = `\r` = `^M` = 13 decimal = 015 octal = 0x0d hexadecimal). When a Windows text file is processed by a Unix utility, each line thus ends with a spurious CR character.

Cygwin utilities are straight ports of Linux tools. They don't handle Windows text files specially, so the CR characters do end up as line content. In your pasted file, there's a CR before each comma.

You can convert the files to Unix format first:

```
dos2unix *.csv
paste -d , test1.csv test2.csv > paste.csv
```

Or you can just remove the CR characters. Here it works to remove them from inside the line; some other text manipulations would require removing them before processing.

```
paste -d , test1.csv test2.csv | tr -d '\r' > paste.csv
```